# Why do some nuclear tests feature what seems to be an additional fireball on top?

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics, explosions

Have a look at this frame from footage recorded during Operation Hardtack I - Test POPLAR
[image: Still from a recording of an RB-57D Canberra surveilling the nuclear test Hardtack I - POPLAR]
Clearly the bit on top is extra hot, and it seems to be above the main fireball, or at least not part of the sphere. If you look at [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6PGZ4yiJqY), you'll see the ball actually forms earlier, gets relatively more incandescent and pushed up by the front of the main fireball, and dissipate rapidly after. While typing this out I found some more recently declassified footage and it seems to be a tiny explosion occurring at the top of the fireball, see e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JJfIjlU7Z8). At frame ~550 the sphere deforms and around frame ~1140 it can be seen as a separate explosion.

So what is this? One option I came across was that this is the fission primary's own explosion, but I don't understand why it would form so late, and why it would "escape" the main fireball like that.
Another option might be that there were some vacuum tubes used for measuring X-rays at a remote sensing station, similar to how there were during the Castle Bravo test. This led about 1kt of energy going faster than the main fireball to escape as a side explosion, see e.g. [image: Series of frames from a recording of test Castle Bravo showing about 1kt of energy escaping the main fireball through vacuum tubes and exiting at a measuring station]

If that was the case, perhaps the main fireball then caught up and compressed the smaller fireball, making it shine so brightly? One issue with this is that POPLAR was a deliverable bomb suspended in a barge and the research was more geared to radiological exclusion and fallout, whereas Castle Bravo was still a demonstrator of non-cryogenic fuel, and so I'm not sure vacuum tubes were necessary for the former.

Hopefully someone can shine a light on this :)

Comment: I don't think they contain answers to your specific questions, but if you want to know more about the physics of nuclear weapons, Scott Manley's [Going Nuclear](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYu7z3I8tdEnTQMXpP6gYN9DVm_DjXza9) series of videos is a good source.